# Assistance with converting a module to a class

Tags: python, class, oop

I have created the following Python module `time_as_words.py` and would like to convert the following to a Python class. I have very little experience in object oriented programming and would like to get some advice from the community in how I can convert my following Python module into a Python class.

time_as_words.py:

```
"""
Created on 04 June 2017

Convert 24hr format time

into time as words

@author: PeterW
"""
# import site-packages and modules
import sys
import re
import time
import argparse


def validate_time_format(input_time):
    """Validate that input string
    matches require 24hr time format"""
    regexp_object = re.compile(r'^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|23:59)$')
    if regexp_object.match(input_time):
        print("Processing: {0} into words".format(input_time))
        time_str = input_time
    else:
        print("{0} doesn't match required input format: 00:00 to 23:59".format(input_time))
        sys.exit()
    return time_str


def extract_time(time_str):
    """convert time from 24hr format
    into 12hours, minutes, period"""
    period_type = {'AM': 'before midday', 'PM': 'after midday'}
    try:
        time_object = time.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M')
        suffix = time.strftime('%p', time_object)
        hours = int(time.strftime('%I', time_object))
        minutes = time_object[4]
        period = period_type.get(suffix)
#         print("{0}:{1} {2}".format(hours, str(minutes).zfill(2), period))
        return hours, minutes, period
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)


def time_lookup():
    """create dictionary
    to lookup equivalent word
    of integer number"""
    words_lookup = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five',
                    6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine', 10: 'ten',
                    11: 'eleven', 12: 'twelve', 13: 'thirteen',
                    14: 'fourteen', 16: 'sixteen', 17: 'seventeen',
                    18: 'eighteen', 19: 'nineteen', 20: 'twenty',
                    21: 'twenty one', 22: 'twenty two', 23: 'twenty three',
                    24: 'twenty four', 25: 'twenty five', 26: 'twenty six',
                    27: 'twenty seven', 28: 'twenty eight', 29: 'twenty nine'}
    return words_lookup


def time_as_words(input_time):
    """convert 24hr format time
    into time as words"""
    time_str = validate_time_format(input_time)
    hours, minutes, period = extract_time(time_str)
    words_lookup = time_lookup()
    if hours == 12:
        hours2 = words_lookup.get(1)
    else:
        hours2 = words_lookup.get(hours+1)
    if hours == 12 and minutes == 0 and period == 'before midday':
        time = 'Midnight'
    elif hours == 12 and minutes == 0 and period == 'after midday':
        time = 'Midday'
    elif minutes == 0:
        time = "{0} o'clock {1}.".format(str(words_lookup.get(hours)).title(),
                                         period)
    elif minutes == 15:
        time = "Quarter past {0} {1}.".format(words_lookup.get(hours),
                                              period)
    elif minutes == 30:
        time = "Half past {0} {1}.".format(words_lookup.get(hours),
                                           period)
    elif minutes == 45:
        time = "Quarter to {0} {1}.".format(hours2,
                                            period)
    elif minutes < 30:
        min_str = str(words_lookup.get(minutes)).capitalize()
        time = "{0} minute{1} past {2} {3}.".format(min_str,
                                                    "" if minutes == 1 else "s",
                                                    words_lookup.get(hours),
                                                    period)
    else:
        min_str = str(words_lookup.get(60 - minutes)).capitalize()
        time = '{0} minute{1} to {2} {3}.'.format(min_str,
                                                  "" if 60 - minutes == 1 else "s",
                                                  hours2,
                                                  period)
    print(time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Convert 24hr format time into time as words")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--input_time", metavar="time", type=str, required=True,
                        help='input time in the following format 00:00 to 23:59')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    time_as_words(input_time=args.input_time)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Official documentation on how to write Python classes. A little googling never hurts. :-)

Comment: Why do you think this should be converted into a class?